# Combine two MTLTextures into CIImage with Alpha Channel Transparency

Tags: swift, metal, ciimage

I need to combine two `MTLTextures` into a single `CIImage` with transparency control via the alpha channel. I am hoping this is obviously easy, and I just don't know how to do it.

Right now the code looks something like this:

```
outputImage = CIImage(mtlTexture: primaryTexture!, options: [CIImageOption.colorSpace: colorSpace])
```

I need to add a `secondaryTexture` as well as an alpha channel control, such as '0.8'.

I have been googling a lot (perhaps using the wrong terms?) I have not been able to find answers.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want the alpha control to be multiplied by the existing alpha channel in the source image (if any) or replace any existing alpha channel? This is similar to _source-over compositing_, but I don't know if any single CI filter allows you to modulate/override the source alpha channel. This can certainly be done with a custom filter kernel, though.

Comment: Thanks Warren. To clarify, my original thought was to just have a transparency control on the the second image. The situation is this: I am running a kernel filter on the second texture, but the filter is sometimes too strong. I want to be able to adjust the strength of the filter effect. I thought the best way to do this may be to layer the new filtered image over the original image and adjust the transparency of it to reach the desired effect. Thoughts?
Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if that could be achieved with `CIDissolveTransition`, treating time as "effect strength."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll give it a try!

Comment: Thanks @warrenm! CIDissolveTransition worked well. I am blending the two images super smoothly with a UISlider. I am doing this on a live video feed -- it's far from terrible, but it is a bit hefty on resources. Do you know if finding a way to blend the MTLTextures would help make this run more smoothly?
For now this works amazingly well though. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm pleased this worked! As far as optimization, I suppose it somewhat depends on what other filter operations you're doing. When possible, Core Image composes filters together at the shader source level, so I'd question whether it's possible in principle to create a lighter/faster hybrid solution without going all the way to a fully custom Metal solution.